# using make_column_transformer with OnehotEncoder and StandaScaler + passthrough

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am unable to use **remainder='passthrough'** whenever I am using the StandardScaler and OnehotEncoding at the same time. Whichever way I am putting it, I have a problem. it's either keyword before argument,a problem with the **fit_tranform**... you name it. Here what I am doing :

```
trans_cols= make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),['job', 'marital', 'education', 
 'default','housing','loan','contact','month','poutcome']),remainder='passthrough')

trans_cols.fit_transform(X)

here are my columns:
Index(['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'balance', 'housing',
   'loan', 'contact', 'month', 'duration', 'campaign', 'pdays', 'previous',
   'poutcome', 'y'],
  dtype='object')
```

The code above works, I am just not able to combine the 2 estimators when using the **remainder** key argument. Here is why I am trying:

```
trans_cols= make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),['job', 'marital', 'education', 'default','housing','loan',
                                                  'contact','month','poutcome']),remainder='passthrough',

(StandardScaler(),['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'balance',
                  'housing','loan', 'contact', 'month', 'duration',
                  'campaign', 'pdays', 'previous','poutcome']))
```

However, the above does not work until I remove `remainder` and keep 2 tuples. Which understandable. however, doing that it is trying to encode some of my numeric  and I have a a message telling that it encountered some columns that have float.Plus my accuracy drops severely.

Comment: Are you aiming to apply OHE on the listed columns and a StandardScaler on the remaining columns?

Comment: Can you show us, how are you applying the standard scaler?

Comment: @KRKirov . I am trying to apply the OHE to some of the column and the StandardScaler to all once the OHE is done

Comment: @Venkatachalam. I have updated and showed how I am trying to use. bear in mind I tried many ways. it does not seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred practice is not to use StandardScaler on one-hot-encoded columns. The first example below demonstrates the application of OHE on the categorical variables and StandardScaler on the numeric columns. The second example, shows the sequential application of OHE on selected columns and StandardScaler on all columns, but this is not recommended.

Example_1:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat_Var': np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], size=5),
                   'Num_Var': np.arange(5)})

cat_cols = ['Cat_Var']
num_cols = ['Num_Var']

col_transformer = make_column_transformer(
        (OneHotEncoder(), cat_cols),
        remainder=StandardScaler())

X = col_transformer.fit_transform(df)
```

Output:

```
df
Out[57]: 
  Cat_Var  Num_Var
0       b        0
1       a        1
2       b        2
3       a        3
4       a        4

X
Out[58]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        , -1.41421356],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        , -0.70710678],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  1.41421356]])
```

Example 2:

```
col_transformer_2 = ColumnTransformer(
        [('cat_transform', OneHotEncoder(), cat_cols)],
        remainder='passthrough'
        )

pipe = Pipeline(
        [
         ('col_tranform', col_transformer_2),
         ('standard_scaler', StandardScaler())
         ])

X_2 = pipe.fit_transform(df)
```

Output:

```
X_2
Out[62]: 
array([[-1.22474487,  1.22474487, -1.41421356],
       [ 0.81649658, -0.81649658, -0.70710678],
       [-1.22474487,  1.22474487,  0.        ],
       [ 0.81649658, -0.81649658,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.81649658, -0.81649658,  1.41421356]])
```

Comment: thanks. I just didn't know that. I usually scale my binary variables. thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Hey, I recommend critically evaluating your own question, to see what is missing from it. Things to consider: Is it necessary to have a question with all columns from your data set?, Where are the necessary imports?, Have you provided a toy data set and what is the error message you are getting? The last paragraph in your question is really difficult to decipher. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Making some additions to KRKirov's answer as it might be useful as well.

As you are using make_column_transformer, it do preprocessing your features in the given order. So the remainder (all features that are untouched during processing) should come at the end.

The problem with your code is that you pass the remainder parameter at the middle, so all features that remained from process goes to there. And you can't do processing after that. So first, do all the special processing first then do processing with other features with remainder parameter.

Here I will explain it with the codes.

(1) importing

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
onhe = OneHotEncoder()
scaler = StandardScaler()
```

(2) I will create basic DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['m', 'f','f','m'],
                       'age':[45,25,10,31], 
                       'married':['y','y','n','y'],
                       'salary':[1000,300,370,500],
                       'child':[5, 1,0,3]})
print(df)
```

(3) Let's say we want to do encoding for sex and married columns, standard scaling for age and salary columns and leave the child column as it is.

```
transforming = make_column_transformer((onhe,['sex','married']),
 (scaler,['age', 'salary']),
    remainder = 'passthrough')
     
processed_df = transforming.fit_transform(df)
print(processed_df)
```

Note that remainder is being assigned at the end of the process.
What is more, if you want to do scaler in all remaining features ('age','salary', 'child'), then you can use:

```
transforming_1 = make_column_transformer((onhe, ['sex', 'married']), remainder = scaler)
processed_df_1 = transforming_1.fit_transform(df)
print(processed_df_1)
```

It will encode two given columns then do StandardScaling for all remaining columns.

And when it comes to your situation, your code (from which you got an error), should look like this:

```
trans_cols= make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),['job', 'marital', 'education', 'default','housing','loan','contact','month','poutcome']),(StandardScaler(),['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'balance','housing','loan', 'contact', 'month', 'duration','campaign', 'pdays', 'previous','poutcome']),remainder='passthrough')
```